# It is possible to get a random number defined by a string tag? Like {1-100}

Tags: php

I would like to get a random value between two numbers in a string. For example, a string {1-100} returning something like rand (1,100). It's possible?

Comment: Very possible. What have you tried? There are many, many ways of achieving this.

Comment: Naive way, remove the first and last characters (`{` and `}`), explode on `-`, convert the strings in the resulting array to numbers, use them as parameters for `rand`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
       $string = "{1-100}";
       $split = split("-",$string);
       if (count($split)==2){
           $lower = intval(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $split[0]));
           $upper = intval(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $split[1]));
           $random = rand($lower, $upper);
       }
```